# Strange exceptions out of nowhere

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I'm working on a .net Middleware structure and recently I suddenly got the following exception after about 20-30 seconds when I was debugging the application.

```
 System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException was unhandled
     Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
     Additional information: Ambiguous match found.
```

Strangely I did not change a single line a code, I'm really just debugging it. When I install it as a service in release mode it works. Furthermore it is working on other computers.
When I first encountered this strange behaviour I re-installed my computer and suddenly the exception was gone. But after the second start of the Middle ware in debug mode the exception was back. 
Just as a note, I did not change anything in the DEBUG preferences.

Here are some more details from the output log when the exception occurs.

> System.Transactions Critical: 0 : 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled
>   exception
>
> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Ambiguous
>   match found.   at
>   System.DefaultBinder.FindMostDerivedNewSlotMeth(MethodBase[] match,
>   Int32 cMatches)

hermeskim.Middleware.Service.vshost.exeSystem.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException,

at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)

at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)

at System.Type.GetMethod(String name)
   at System.Activities.Debugger.State.GetMethodInfo(Boolean withPriming)
   at System.Activities.Debugger.StateManager.InvokeWorker(Object islandArguments, VirtualStackFrame stackFrame)
   at System.Activities.Debugger.ThreadWorkerController.Worker(Boolean isAtStartup)

at System.Activities.Debugger.ThreadWorkerController.WorkerThreadProc()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException: Ambiguous match found.
   at System.DefaultBinder.FindMostDerivedNewSlotMeth(MethodBase[] match, Int32 cMatches)

at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)

at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConvention, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at System.Type.GetMethod(String name)
   at System.Activities.Debugger.State.GetMethodInfo(Boolean withPriming)
   at System.Activities.Debugger.StateManager.InvokeWorker(Object islandArguments, VirtualStackFrame stackFrame)
   at System.Activities.Debugger.ThreadWorkerController.Worker(Boolean isAtStartup)

at System.Activities.Debugger.ThreadWorkerController.WorkerThreadProc()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Could you add the code that you're trying to call?

Comment: Looks like your references aren't correct. Maybe you're adding some system library manually or you've got a weird assembly manifest?

Comment: I cannot add any code unfortunately. The exception start randomly after a while when the application is already running. I cannot see where it is coming from. The debugger tells me if I want to see more details I would have to disable 'Just my code' and load the symbols. But even if I do that, I do not get any more information. One more note: The exception happens in the debugger thread itself.

Comment: @Hannes Last time I got behavior like this (Debug fall , normal run continues like no buddy's business)
It was infinite loop of calling function that calls it self 
so you better start by disabling stuff that look strange and look for some strange calling of referencing

Comment: But the code is the same for at least a month, and we are debugging it all the time. And I'm the only one who gets these exceptions. Is it possible that windows update could do this? I'm the only one who has them enabled by default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the config files where I accidentally started the same Workflow 2 times.